# Get Sharepoint Central administration from SpFarm Object

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, managed-metadata, central-administration, term-store

I have requirement to create the termGroup in TermStore.

```
 private void ProvisionTermGroups(SPFarm farm)
            {
                DebugWriter.Write("Started processing of term groups", this);
                foreach (TermGroup termGroup in this.Farm.ManagedMetadata)
                {

                        if (termGroup.Action == Action.Add)
                        {
                            //TODO: Code processing of term groups
                            foreach (TermSet termSet in termGroup.TermSets)
                            {
                                //TODO: Code processing of term sets
                                foreach (Term term in termSet.Terms)
                                {
                                    //TODO: Code processing of term
                                }
                            }
                        }
                  }
        }
```

My code structure as above.

How can i get the Site collection context of central administration from the FARM object to provision Term Group in Term Store ?

I have tried getting the default server from the **local.farm** but i am not able to get the Sharepoint Central Administration of the "**SpServer**" ?

Can i get term-store Object from the Service Instances in farm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using below code

```
var service = SPFarm.Local.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>(string.Empty);
foreach (SPWebApplication webApplication in service.WebApplications)
{
    //GetAllSitesFromWebApplication(webApplication.Sites);
}
```

Comment: Not working as expected. Need something else.

Answer (score 0):

Find one [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657906/how-do-i-obtain-central-administration-site-url-programmatically) 
 Try this

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication centralWeb =
SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local;
```